# remove index.php on codeigniter in one.com

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is .htaccess but not work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        #Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/configSite/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|public|robots.txt)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the config file:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I want to access http://serv.er/controller/ instead of http://serv.er/index.php/controller/

How is it done?

Thanks

Comment: one.Com doesn't support RewriteBase

Comment: I talk to them they say they support and in localhost not work

Comment: check mod_rewrite is enabled or not

Comment: it is enabled in the server and local

Comment: @Esloop strange my solution should work then

Comment: i use two control the welcome with this all work, and the two controller, with this nathing work.

Comment: @Esloop sorry but I didn't understand what you said now. Explain in detail

Comment: i use two controller in codeigniter default controller welcome (with this controller the .htaccess work), but with the second controller, nothing work only can access with serv.er/index.php/secondController

Comment: what does routes.php - $route['default_controller'] contain ?

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "controllerOne";

Comment: The error was that the controller and the application folder was equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Make sure you have enabled **rewrite_module** on your Apache modules

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|indexcp\.php?|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/.-]+)$ index.php?/welcome/$1
```

Open config.php :-

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';  //your site name

$config['uri_protocol']= 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: @Esloop mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: I talk to them now they say they support

Answer (score 0):

check you php  config for mod_rewrite  enabled 
in your server create file info.php contain

```
    <?php
php_info();
?>
```

then run `http://localhost/info.php`

where you could check mod_rewrite  enabled

Comment: in the localhost its ok, but in the server not but i talk I talk to them they say they support

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule .* /index.php/$1 [L]
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.one.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "controller";
```